# Is there any way to instruct Windows to ignore the “write-only” mechanical switch on SD cards?

Tags: windows-7, sd-card

I have a bunch of SD cards that do not have the little plastic switch for the read only setting. so Windows thinks it’s write protected or something. The card **is not** write protected by the *software* lock present on the SD card standard.

I’m using one with tape over the notch and it’s ugly. Also, the Thinkpad slot drags on the tape all the time so I’m afraid it will might loose in there eventually.

So, is there any way to tell Windows to ignore this lame write-protect feature?

I’m not interested on the SD card itself as it’s irrelevant for the issue at hand. Read this question as being about a `5.25” floppy disk drive` instead of an SD card if you wish. I’m pretty sure the Windows settings are the same for both, really.

I’m [aware](https://superuser.com/questions/354473/is-the-lock-mechanism-on-an-sd-card-hardware-firmware-or-software-driver-os) that there are 3 ways to secure an SD card. I’m talking about only the mechanical switch, which is the responsibility of the host to handle.

Comment: Were your cards always treated by Windows as read-only ever since you bought them, or is this a recent occurrence?

Comment: @Karan always like that. i want to override that write-only check siliness in windows. it's done by software only. i'm pretty sure it's possible as i've done that in the past, i'm just forgetting the search term... it's a registry key

Comment: I do not think that this question is a dupe, when it is specific to the windows platform. When the intention is to override it in the windows system. While the original (useful) Q&A confirms that there is no electrical connection changed in the card itself, in no aspect of the question is a question on how to override it. although a linux only solution is added to the answers. I have the same BS taped up cards that have not had any vast read/writes, and it would be ultimatly invaluable to be able to use these without destroying the readers In windows specific.

Comment: @Psycogeek, agree. for me it's common knowledge the answer on the so called "duplicate". and i even stated that as fact on the question with the sole purpose of not confusing people with that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the following as a .REG file, import it and see if it works:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies]
"WriteProtect"=dword:00000000
```

if it doesn't, I don't know of any other way to forcibly make your card reader's driver ignore the physical write-protect switch or the card's [internal write protection mechanism](https://superuser.com/a/354497/138343) if one exists (it's an optional part of the spec, and only implemented on some cards).

Comment: will be testing that as soon as im back at that box!

Comment: giving up, never got another windows box to test this. so i will accept it :) thanks.

Comment: After almost a decade, this answer currently only has 2 upvotes.  Is this technique reliable?