# Effectiveness of SD Card write protect switch as protection from viruses

Tags: virus, sd-card

Given that [the SD card write protect switch simply indicates to the OS that it is switched](https://superuser.com/questions/354473/is-the-lock-mechanism-on-an-sd-card-hardware-firmware-or-software-driver-os), and doesn't prevent writes to the medium, how effective is enabling write protect against viruses?  Are viruses that can overcome such a measure common?  Do they exist at all?

Comment: Related: [How to instruct windows to ignore the 'write-only' mechanical switch on SD cards?](http://superuser.com/questions/578716/how-to-instruct-windows-to-ignore-the-write-only-mechanical-switch-on-sd-cards)